# Why does building and image with docker compose fail but succeeds without it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build an image with docker compose and it fails, however it works with just docker. I have read some SO posts saying that the error thrown when failing happens when a file/folder cannot be found in the Dockerfile. The build works when building with docker so I dont know why it wouldn't work with docker-compose. Why is this happening?

The structure for this project is this:

```
parent_proj
 |_proj
   |_Dockerfile
 |_docker-compose.yml
```

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  integrations:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: proj/Dockerfile
      network: host
    image: int
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Here is the Dockerfile inside proj/

```
FROM openjdk:11
USER root
#RUN apt-get bash
ARG JAR_FILE=target/proj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app2.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "/app2.jar"]
```

When I'm inside the proj folder. I can run

```
docker build . -t proj
```

The above succeeds and I can subsequently run the container. However when I am in parent_proj and run `docker compose build` it fails with the error message

> failed to compute cache key: failed to walk
> /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount316454722/target: lstat
> /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount316454722/target: no such file or
> directory

Why does this happen? How can I build successfully with docker-compose without restructuring the project?

thanks

Comment: Try `context: proj` and removing `dockerfile: proj/Dockerfile`. When you build with docker the `COPY` command finds files relative to the current folder, when you build with compose it uses the folder passed in `context` as the current directory which you set to the parent folder

Comment: I tried that. I get a different error: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: resolve : lstat /Users/id/projects/org/parent_proj/proj/proj: no such file or directory

Comment: Remove `dockerfile: ` too

Answer (score 2):

Your Compose build options and the `docker build` options you show are different.  The successful command is (where `-f Dockerfile` is the default):

```bash
docker build ./proj   -t proj    # -f Dockerfile
#            context:    image:       dockerfile:
```

But your Compose setup is running

```bash
docker build .         -t img     -f proj/Dockerfile
#            context:     image:     dockerfile:
```

Which one is right?  In the Dockerfile, you

```bash
COPY target/proj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /some/container/path
```

That `target/...` source path is always relative to the build-context directory (Compose `context:` option, the directory parameter to `docker build`), even if it looks like an absolute path and even if the Dockerfile is in a different directory.  If that `target` directory is a subdirectory of `proj` then you need the first form.

There's a shorthand Compose `build:` syntax if the only thing you need to specify is the context directory, and I'd use that here.  If you don't specifically care what the image name is (you're not pushing it to a registry) then Compose can pick a reasonable name on its own; you don't need to specify `image:`.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  integrations:
    build: ./proj
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```